# Answer does not get shown in a message box

Tags: javascript, html, output

I have 2 random numbers being generated determined by the user input. I then have a box where you enter your answer to the addition problem, but it does not show whether you are right or not.

I've tried changing the buttons and what kind of message they output.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Math</title>
    <h1>Math Questions<h1/>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function RandomNum1() {
        var low = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Low").value);
        var high = parseFloat(document.getElementById("High").value);      
        var Random;
        Random = Math.floor((Math.random()*high )+ low);
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Random;
      }

      function RandomNum2() {
        var low2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Low").value);
        var high2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("High").value);      
        var Random2;
        Random2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*high2 )+ low2);
        document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = Random2;
      }
      function Answer(userGuess) {
        var answer = Random+Random2;          
        if (userGuess==answer) {
          document.getElementById("outMsgBox").innerHTML="You are correct!!!";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("outMsgBox").innerHTML="Sorry, try again. :(";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <p>Enter the range of numbers you would like. <br />
       Minimum <input type="numeric" id="Low" size="10" value="" /> <br />
       Maximum <input type="numeric" id="High" size="10" value="" />
    </p>
    <input type="button" value="Generate First " onclick="RandomNum1();" hr="" />  <input type="button" value="Generate Second" onclick="RandomNum2();" hr="" />
    <p><div id="output" type="numeric"></div>+<div class="OutputBox" id="output2" type="numeric"></div></p>

    <p>Enter your answer here. <input type=numeric id="userGuess" min="1" max="1000"/> </p>  
    <input type="button" style="background-color:lightgreen" value="Check Answer" onclick="Answer(document.getElementById('userGuess').value);"/>
    <div id="outMsgBox" style="border-style:groove; border-color:green"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to show if you answered right or not but it does not show anything when you click "check answer".

Comment: check console for error: `Random is not defined` - because Random and Random2 are function scoped variables not visible inside `Answer` function - move var Random and var Random2 to global scope - see https://jsfiddle.net/taprqczk/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are declaring the variables `Random, Random2` as a local variable.
Try placing this line at the start of the script

```
var Random, Random2;
```

This will define them as global variables, which means any part of your script can acces the variables. You then need to remove the definitions for the variables `var Random` and `var Random2`from the functions so you don't override the global variables.